# How to use F.getValueSymbolTable()

Tags: c++, llvm

I wanna get all the local variables in a function.

```cpp
void getLocalVariables(Function &F) {
  ValueSymbolTable *vst = F.getValueSymbolTable();
  for (auto vs : vst) {  // here it says: This scope-based "for" statement required the appropriate "begin" function, but was not found
    auto s = vs.getKey();
    auto v = vs.getValue();
  }
}
```

The error is that: `This scope-based "for" statement required the appropriate "begin" function, but was not found`. So **how can I correct my code**? Tks.

Comment: Range-based `for` requires a range to iterate. A single pointer cannot produce a range. You will have to do something else, but I know not what.

Comment: Can you once try changing the for loop as follows: ```for (auto vs : (*vst))```, provided the ```class ValueSymbolTable``` implements the iterator functionality ```begin()```, ```end()``` etc., I think this change should work

Comment: `ValueSymbolTable` provides an iterator, yes, but one that iterates over the values, not the local variables. IR is an [SSA language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) so "local variables" are not part of the language, and most values don't have anything to do with variables in the source language. Of course one can write Fortran in any language, but noone can expect other people's code to be Fortran instead of the actual language.

Answer (score 0):

I check the documentation for `ValueSymbolTable`, and finally find how to use it. But actually, as **arnt** said, they are not local variables in source code. They are temporary variables generated by IR.

```cpp
void getLocalVariables(Function &F) {
      // not test yet
      ValueSymbolTable *vst = F.getValueSymbolTable();
      errs() << (*vst).size() << "\n.";

      for (ValueSymbolTable::iterator VI = vst->begin(), VE = vst->end(); VI != VE; ++VI) {
        Value *V = VI->getValue();
        if (!isa<GlobalValue>(V) || cast<GlobalValue>(V)->hasLocalLinkage()) {
          if (!V->getName().startswith("llvm.dbg"))
            // Set name to "", removing from symbol table!
            V->setName("");
        }
      }
    }
```